# Enable MySQL syslog to log aborted connections and access-denied

Tags: mysql, linux

What is the command in mysql that is required to that I can implement aborted connections and access-denied logs to be written to the syslog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands are first to see what your settings are:

```
select @@general_log; -- a 1 indicates it is turned on for capture
select @@general_log_file; -- the file that it logs to
select @@datadir; -- directory location where the log lives
```

To turn logging on for the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), use the following:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'; -- 0 is off, 1 is on
```

Note that the `datadir` is read-only and requires a restart of the server after changes. Basically, don't change this. It is the home of your database schemas.

For expanded connection failures perform a

```
select @@log_warnings; -- make a note of your prior setting
set global log_warnings=2; -- setting above 1 increases output
```

The immediate above relates to the Error log written out in the same datadir.

See the Percona article [Auditing login attempts in MySQL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/) and my prior answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38394479).