# can't enable MySql general query log file on wamp running mysql 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am having trouble activating a general query log file in WAMP  I have viewed many threads and can't seem to get it to write a log.

I have tried both good queries and bad queries to try to trip the log.

Any suggestions?

This is my my.ini

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data
log-output = FILE
general-log = 1
general_log_file=C:/wamp/logs/general-query.log
```

Comment: What are some of the threads and things you've tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in `general-log`. It should be `general_log`

And then a mysql restart.

And check your variables, after a restart such as

```
select @@general_log; -- 0 (that means OFF). 1 is ON.
select @@general_log_file; -- GUYSMILEY.log
select @@datadir; -- C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\
select @@version; -- 5.6.31-log
```

To set a dynamic variable to override a cnf or ini file setting, do something similar to:

```
set GLOBAL general_log=1;
```

[image]

Remember that it is `datadir`, not `basedir`. You may need to open up the viewing of hidden folders on Windows to see the `\ProgramData` if that is where you `datadir` points.

And lastly, you don't need to trick it with an error sql statement. The General Query Log is for all queries.

For a screenshot view of it, see [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38394479). Remember, it is for all queries. So turn it off, make a copy, delete, turn back on, it regenerates. Don't forget too that having the General Log activated in production slows down performance.

Also, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6479183) from Gryphius.

**Edit** (per your question in comments).

Changes to dynamic variables are fleeting if not mirrored in cnf or ini settings. Meaning, they are reset upon mysql restarting.

I don't know a way to turn off Error logging nor would I probably want to. Errors are infrequent and knowledge of them is quite important. So the below should satisfy 3 of your 4 curiosities:

```
show variables like '%error%';
show variables like '%slow%';

log_error -- string for filename

slow_query_log -- set to 'ON' or 1, 'OFF' or 0
slow_query_log_file; --- string for filename
```

Then there is always `show variables;`

More on the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html). If you set the `long_query_time` high enough, it will effectively filter out more noise. It is in seconds, from 0 to 10. And a [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/11/07/poor-mans-query-logging/) article though dated.

```
select @@long_query_time;
+-------------------+
| @@long_query_time |
+-------------------+
|         10.000000 |
+-------------------+
```

Note, I can't seem to set the above with a `SET GLOBAL` stmt. So it appears to be a setting only for the cnf or ini file. But you can do the following:

```
select @@slow_query_log; -- to see current value
select @@slow_query_log_file; -- to see current value (file in datadir)
select @@datadir; -- to see current value

set global slow_query_log=0; -- Turn Off
-- make a backup of it with a move and rename (See Note1) to a folder below datadir
set global slow_query_log=1; -- Turn it back On (new empty file is created)
```

Note1: Image of file copied, renamed at Note1 point-in-time above. [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFPqD.jpg).

Comment: Setting it from console worked!! I wonder why didn't it set `general_log` to `true` when added in `my.ini`?!!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr  did you restart the server? Is it the .ini that is actually picked up and used? (which can be hard to debug in person, let alone little comment boxes? :p) ... also I have a chat room [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) people sometimes dump mysql questions in. No promises.

Comment: Also I wrote these two up in the Docs section [General](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5102/log-files/18052/general-query-log#t=201610080651188753838) and [Slow query](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5102/log-files#t=201610080651188753838) . As an aside, when I am testing whether a setting is picked up (mainly if the cnf or ini is in the right place in a directory), I test against an innocuous variable like the `verbosity` type variables (depending on your MySQL version). Test to see if the file change is picked up for that variable.

Comment: Hi - thanks for response. I'm sure about the `.ini` file i'm editing. I have successfully set up binary logging using same file (for backup/restore plans), so other settings are definitely being picked from there. Ohh! and yes, i did restart mysql service.